# How to pass parameters to routes using tab navigator (createMaterialBottomTabNavigator)?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am using `createMaterialBottomTabNavigator` and I want to pass parameters to the routes:

```
return (
   <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={home_customers} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Favorites" component={favorite_vendors} />
      <Tab.Screen name="More" component={settings_screen} />
   </Tab.Navigator>
);
```

I could only find an attribute called `initialParams` which I am not sure if it is the right thing to use in this case. So, what I want to do is to **GET** parameters from the previous screen and **PASS** that parameter to each of these three screens!

**UPDATE**

ok, I found out how to GET the parameters but I still don't know how to pass those parameters to route screens!

```
export default function home_customers_bar({ route, navigation }) {
    const current_city_ = route.params.current_user_city_; //here I get the parameter from the previous screen
    
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={home_customers} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Favorites" component={favorite_vendors} />
            <Tab.Screen name="More" component={settings_screen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}
```

Comment: It's recommended to use something like react context for this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#global-props-with-screenprops. Or Redux if you prefer that. You could also set `initialParams` for each screen, but this is of course not a good way to do it if all screens need to access `current_city_`

Comment: @BasvanderLinden actually I need to pass the parameter to only two of the screens. So I can just use initialParams? How can I use it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you only need to pass the data to a limited number of screens you can set the `initialParams` like this:

```
export default function home_customers_bar({route, navigation}) {
  const current_city_ = route.params.current_user_city_; //here I get the parameter from the previous screen

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={home_customers}
        initialParams={{currentCity: current_city_}}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Favorites"
        component={favorite_vendors}
        initialParams={{currentCity: current_city_}}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="More" component={settings_screen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Then you can retrieve the params inside a screen component like this:

```
function home_customers({ route }) {
  const currentCity = route.params.currentCity;

  // Do something with it...
}
```

---

If you're going to be passing this value around to a lot of different components then it's probably better to use something like react context https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#global-props-with-screenprops.

Comment: Why is this not working for me even though it looks like something that should work?

Answer (score 1):

The easier way to achieve this is to use React Context API.

I also tried so hard to pass data and states from one screen to another using bottom tabs in react-native but it just was a heavy task and kept having glitches. You may want to clone this repository and study it. It has different screens so I cannot write the codes here but it is helpful and more uncomplicated.

https://github.com/AnatuGreen/ReactNative-ContextAPI-Sample-App

Comment: not everyone uses functional component. Dont assume that.